# Parsing text file record multiple lines

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to parse a text file where one record could span 4 lines. In the text below I found that 16,145 is the beginning of the record where 88 is the continuation line. The goal is to get the data in a table where Comp Name, Cust Name, Desc, etc are field names.

> 16,145,531299,S,531299,000,000,,36358906393192/
>   
> 88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: AP0042168896 Desc: COMM OF ND Comp Name: 
>   
> 88,COMM OF ND Comp ID: ND TR DPT SEC: CCD Cust Name: Dakota Central Date: 
>   
> 88,11-28-18 Time: 05:52 AM Addenda: 705PA529-Kerry Adam 
>   
> 16,145,520000,S,520000,000,000,,36358906393216/
>   
> 88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: AP0042168908 Desc: COMM OF ND Comp Name: 
>   
> 88,COMM OF ND Comp ID: ND TR DPT SEC: CCD Cust Name: Dakota Central Date: 
>   
> 88,11-28-18 Time: 05:52 AM Addenda: 705PA529-Ladson Maria 
>   
> 16,145,517500,S,517500,000,000,,36361011907140/
>   
> 88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: 368908356002797 Desc: MERCH DEP Comp Name: 
>   
> 88,BANKCARD Comp ID: 1246825337 SEC: CCD Cust Name: WRTI Date: 11-28-18 
>   
> 88,Time: 05:36 AM Addenda: No Addenda

I can read the text file into a textbox easily. My thought is if I can load the file with each new line starting with "16,1" where the "88s" are concatenated with the "16s". 
Below is what I started with.

  Dim fileName As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\Fargo.pdr")

  TextBox1.Text = fileName

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split on the line separator? **Edit** to keep things simple. Assign the string variable to test

```
Dim s As String =
$"16,145,531299,S,531299,000,000,,36358906393192/ 
88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: AP0042168896 Desc: COMM OF ND Comp Name: 
88,COMM OF ND Comp ID: ND TR DPT SEC: CCD Cust Name: Dakota Central Date: 
88,11-28-18 Time: 05:52 AM Addenda: 705PA529-Kerry Adam 
16,145,520000,S,520000,000,000,,36358906393216/ 
88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: AP0042168908 Desc: COMM OF ND Comp Name: 
88,COMM OF ND Comp ID: ND TR DPT SEC: CCD Cust Name: Dakota Central Date: 
88,11-28-18 Time: 05:52 AM Addenda: 705PA529-Ladson Maria 
16,145,517500,S,517500,000,000,,36361011907140/ 
88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: 368908356002797 Desc: MERCH DEP Comp Name: 
88,BANKCARD Comp ID: 1246825337 SEC: CCD Cust Name: WRTI Date: 11-28-18 
88,Time: 05:36 AM Addenda: No Addenda"
```

You probably want to clean up the text. Up to you

```
s = s.Replace("88,", "") ' remove "88,"
s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "") ' remove newlines (whatever newline char/string you use)
```

And this operation of splitting on `16,145` almost couldn't be simpler. You have your collection in a single line of code:

```
Dim lines = s.Split({"16,145,"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

resulting `lines` variable holds three lines:

> 531299,S,531299,000,000,,36358906393192/ 
>   
> 88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: AP0042168896 Desc: COMM OF ND Comp Name: 
>   
> 88,COMM OF ND Comp ID: ND TR DPT SEC: CCD Cust Name: Dakota Central Date: 
>   
> 88,11-28-18 Time: 05:52 AM Addenda: 705PA529-Kerry Adam 
>   
> 520000,S,520000,000,000,,36358906393216/ 
>   
> 88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: AP0042168908 Desc: COMM OF ND Comp Name: 
>   
> 88,COMM OF ND Comp ID: ND TR DPT SEC: CCD Cust Name: Dakota Central Date: 
>   
> 88,11-28-18 Time: 05:52 AM Addenda: 705PA529-Ladson Maria 
>   
> 517500,S,517500,000,000,,36361011907140/ 
>   
> 88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: 368908356002797 Desc: MERCH DEP Comp Name: 
>   
> 88,BANKCARD Comp ID: 1246825337 SEC: CCD Cust Name: WRTI Date: 11-28-18 
>   
> 88,Time: 05:36 AM Addenda: No Addenda

---

Now, to parse the records themselves, there are a few ways to do that. The simplest way (and all I am going to do for you) is to assume that the order of the fields is always the same. Let's make a struct to hold a record:

```
Public Structure Record
    Public ReadOnly Property CustID As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Desc As String
    Public ReadOnly Property CompName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property CompID As String
    Public ReadOnly Property SEC As String
    Public ReadOnly Property CustName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Timestamp As Date
    Public ReadOnly Property Addenda As String
    Public Sub New(custID As String, desc As String, compName As String,
                   compID As String, sec As String, custName As String,
                   [date] As String, time As String, addenda As String)
        Me.CustID = custID.Trim()
        Me.Desc = desc.Trim()
        Me.CompName = compName.Trim()
        Me.CompID = compID.Trim()
        Me.SEC = sec.Trim()
        Me.CustName = custName.Trim()
        Me.Addenda = addenda.Trim()
        Me.Timestamp = DateTime.Parse($"{[date].Trim()} {time.Trim()}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

It has a constructor which sets its properties and combines the date and time.

Now you can use this code to create a list of records:

```
Dim fieldNames = {"Cust ID:", "Desc:", "Comp Name:", "Comp ID:", "SEC:", "Cust Name:", "Date:", "Time:", "Addenda:"}
Dim records As New List(Of Record)()
For Each line In lines
    Dim values = line.Split(fieldNames, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    records.Add(New Record(values(1), values(2), values(3), values(4), values(5), values(6), values(7), values(8), values(9)))
Next
```

Inspecting the first record in the debugger:

[image]

Note: removing the `88,` and `NewLine`s seems required in the end, else your values would be interleaved with them.

Comment: Careful with replacing 88 though, it will also replace any other instance of 88 within the data.  EG: 512658823 would become 5126523

Comment: @Peter except there is a comma in the token too. So only `88,` is removed. I had noted removal of that token is optional too

Comment: djv, it sounds like what I'm looking for where the example above produces three lines of data where the '88' moved up to the line with the 16,145.  However,  I'm getting the same result as my starting point. Here's what I have.                                                          Dim s As String
        For Each s In File.ReadAllLines("c:\Fargo.pdr")
            s = s.Replace("88,", "")
            s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")                                 Dim lines = s.Split({"16,145,"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
        Next

Comment: @hutty i'm editing the answer because I guess it was too complicated. More to follow...

Comment: @djv I'm looking at it. Thanks for pointing me in the direction.

Comment: @djv  Are you using a datatable to load list? In your example, there are only 8 fields, as there are 19 fields per line in the textbox. I expanded the structure, but getting the "index was outside the bounds of the array. Here's one line of hundreds:    16,145,1563,S,1563,000,000,,18361008388632/ ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: ACH010014083665 Desc: HCCLAIMPMT Comp Name: HORIZON Comp ID: 3220999690 SEC: PPD Cust Name: BROWN UNIVERSITY MEDI Date: 12-28-18 Time: 05:36 AM Addenda: No Addenda

Comment: This solution requires all 9 fields to be present in each record, and for them to be in a consistent order. If one is missing then how do you handle it? I guess that is how you get an index out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression pattern to iterate over each set of content between the "16,145,"'s.

```
Dim regexPattern As String = "(?<=^16,145,)(.|\n)*?(?=(16,145,|\z))"
Dim regex As New Regex(regexPattern , RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim matches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(text)

If matches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each Match As Match In matches
        Dim content As String = Match.Value
    Next
End If
```

Output would be 3 matches, with the first one being:

```
531299,S,531299,000,000,,36358906393192/
88,ACH CREDIT RECEIVED - Cust ID: AP0042168896 Desc: COMM OF ND Comp Name:
​88,COMM OF ND Comp ID: ND TR DPT SEC: CCD Cust Name: Dakota Central Date:
​88,11-28-18 Time: 05:52 AM Addenda: 705PA529-Kerry Adam
```

Comment: You mentioned to be careful with replacing 88, but as you can see the `Comp Name` would be `<crlf>88,COMM OF ND `, so the newline and 88, need to be handled somehow.